# Angular2 - rxjs observe vs dispose?

Tags: angular, rxjs

What's the difference between unsubscribe and disposing ?

e.g.

```
// app-service.ts
{Http} from @angular/core;

export class appService {
   constructor(private http : Http, fooService : FooService) {}
   getAll() {
       // do this
       this.sub = this.fooService.subscribe(
           () => {}, 
           error => throw new Error(error), 
           () => {}
       )
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
      this.sub.dispose();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a `rxjs4` - `rxjs5` difference;

In `rxjs4` there were `Disposable`s that you `dispose()`, now they are `Subscription`s that you `unsubscribe()`

Source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md